# Is there a different option than addTarget on a UIButton

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton

### addTarget

So I know that you can use addTarget on a button
like so:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    func calledMethod(_ sender: UIButton!) {
        print("Clicked")
    }

     override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let btn = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: 30, y: 30, width: 60, height: 30))
        btn.backgroundColor = UIColor.darkGray
        btn.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.calledMethod(_:)), for: UIControlEvents.touchUpInside)
        self.view.addSubview(btn)
    }
}
```

This works absolutely fine but I was just wondering is there another way to detect when something is clicked and run some code when that happens.

Comment: In general, if you are using a `UIButton`, you want to add a target for the specified UIControlEvents. If it's a `UIView` (or some other UI element), you can use touches or you could add a Gesture Recognizer. Highly recommend you read: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/touches_presses_and_gestures

Comment: @jwjbadger Nice question, I had the same query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A button is a subclass of `UIControl`. A `UIControl` is designed to use target/action to specify code to run when the specified action occurs. If you don't want to use that mechanism, you have to create an equivalent.

You could attach a tap gesture recognizer to some other object and set it's userInteractionEnabled flag to true, but gesture recognizers **ALSO** use the target/action pattern.

My suggestion is to "stop worrying and learn to love the button." Just learn to use target/action.

Another possibility: Create a custom subclass of `UIButton` that sets itself up as it's own target at init time (specifically in `init(coder:)` and `init(frame:)`, the 2 init methods you need to implement for view objects.) This button would include an array of closures that its action method would execute if the button was tapped. It would have methods to add or remove closures. You'd then put such a button in your view controller and call the method to add the closure you want.

Comment: Also I have heard of the TouchesBegan function how would you use that?

Comment: When using controls you usually **don't** deal with `touchesBegan`/`touchesEnded`. Instead you add target/actions to the control and it calls the specified selector. If you're implementing a custom control you'd write `touchesBegan`/`touchesEnded` code that would decide when to forward an action to the target. Likewise, if you're implementing a custom view class that responds to touch events you'd set `userInteractionEnabled` to true and then implement those methods.

Comment: Still if you were using a class for the button how would you use touches began/ended?

Answer (score 1):

You can add button in the storyboard and create an outlet for it's action.

```
@IBAction func buttonAction(_ sender: UIButton) {
  //implement your code here
}
```

Comment: More what I was talking about was how you create it programmatically and do all the checking for a touch programmatically.

Comment: For a button, you have a default touch functionality but if you want to handle the same for some views or labels, you can implement tap gestures accordingly. Check https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitapgesturerecognizer for info :)

Comment: This answer is the same as using `addTarget` except the call to `addTarget` is done for you by connecting the button to the action in Interface Builder.

Answer (score 0):

You can also have a look at [RxSwift/RxCocoa](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxSwift) or similar. All the changes and actions are added automatically and you can decide if you want to observe them or not.

The code would look something like this:

```
   let btn = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: 30, y: 30, width: 60, height: 30))
   btn.backgroundColor = UIColor.darkGray
   btn
      .rx
      .tap
      .subscribe(onNext: {
          print("Clicked")
      }).disposed(by: disposeBag)
   view.addSubview(btn)
```